# Duplicate in ec2 instance list with pythonboto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

i made a tool that need to reboot a aws ec2 instances , the reboot works fine but when im listing the servers i have duplicates in the instance id , how i can list the instances without duplications?
https://gist.github.com/jacobamar8/7aa4367ed44c2d7235bc6e0c86ac0056
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
for instance in instances:
    instancename = ''
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if tag["Key"] == 'Name':
            instancename = tag["Value"]
            break;
    t.add_rows([['InstanceID', 'InstanceName', 'IP'], [instance.id, 
     instancename, instance.private_ip_address]])
```

For sorting by instance name, I had to add the instances to a list and sort that. after that added that to TextTable.

```
import boto3
from texttable import Texttable
t = Texttable()
client = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
describe_instance = []
instance = ec2.Instance('id')
instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])


instanceList = []
for instance in instances:
    instancename = ''
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if tag["Key"] == 'Name':
            instancename = tag["Value"]
            row = [['InstanceID', 'InstanceName', 'IP'], [
                        instance.id, instancename, instance.private_ip_address]]
            instanceList.append(row)

instanceList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][1])

for instanceListItem in instanceList:
  t.add_rows(instanceListItem)

print(t.draw())
```

Comment: Thanks that was easy!

Comment: Is there a way to organize the instance names by alphabetical order ?

Comment: yes, but we should do it before adding to text table, i will post the code

Comment: posted the answer. needed another loop